# How to send a file from linux to windows server using ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to send a file from a Linux host over to my windows server. However, I can't seem to get my code to work. I have looked into the documentation and have found that I have to use the `win_copy` module. Though when I use it, nothing happens and it fails. I am not sure if I specify the host in the destination category or the inventory category.

**Code:**

```
   - name: Copy file to windows server
  win_copy:
    src: /home/robert
    dest: user@wvrp00002aa2.domain.name.com:C:\Users\username\Desktop
```

**Error:**

```
TASK [Copy files in windows systems] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [11.110.60.000]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "checksum": "euifnbf74895845ndej8dh733hd74gf7", "dest": "C:\\Users\\robert\\dev", "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 11.110.60.000 closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: powershell: command not found\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "operation": "file_copy", "original_basename": "text.txt", "rc": 127, "size": 20, "src": "/home/robert/text.txt"}
```

Comment: Post the error message. Make it [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @VladimirBotka Ok I just updated the error

Comment: The error is clear "`/bin/sh: powershell: command not found\r\n`".

Comment: @VladimirBotka Still not sure, how to fix it. I have read the documentation and I was under the impression that I could send any file over using ```win_copy```. I'm not sure what the error is for.

Comment: Run it with "-vvv" and post all details. Check installation [Using Ansible and Windows](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_usage.html?highlight=windows#using-ansible-and-windows). Check what connection [plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection.html#plugin-list) is used. Try [pspr](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection/psrp.html#psrp-run-tasks-over-microsoft-powershell-remoting-protocol) or [winrm](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection/winrm.html#winrm-run-tasks-over-microsoft-s-winrm).

Answer (score 0):

Would correct indentation help?

```
  - name: Copy file to windows server
    win_copy:
      src: /home/robert
      dest: user@wvrp00002aa2.domain.name.com:C:\Users\username\Desktop
```